# Mac 0.80b beta - says "database corrupted" and then Bitcoin-Qt quit unexpectedly

Tags: bitcoin-core, mac

I can't run Bitcoin-Qt 0.80 on Mac OS X 10.8 any more.

It starts up then says "System Error: Database Corrupted". I then click OK, and the program "quits unexpectedly"

How do I  start again without losing my wallet. Is it just the wallet.dat file that I need to keep, or others as well if I reinstall? I have encrypted the wallet if that makes any difference  to the files I need to keep.

There are lots of BC in the wallet. I can't afford to lose them!!

Is there another program I can use just to open the wallet?

Comment: What files do I need to delete to get the program working again? I tried deleting everything in "chainstate" directory, it ran for a while then crashed again. There are also "blocks" and a "database" directory. I just don't want to delete anything which is going to make my bitcoins disappear. But I need access to the wallet again obviously.

Comment: Do you have a recent backup of your wallet.dat?   Any backup within the past 100 transactions would have all your private keys.

Comment: Were you running 0.7 and upgraded to 0.8? https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/2305

Answer (score 2):

[Joric's fork of pywallet](https://github.com/joric/pywallet) can read a wallet.dat, decrypt it with your pass phrase and then you can export the keys.  But if it is corrupted and Bitcoin-Qt can't read it then pywallet may fare no better.

Doesn't hurt to give it a try.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. What I did in the end was import the wallet into blockchain.info/wallet. That worked very well, even with the encrypted wallet.

Comment: @petesmith please post it as an answer, for future reference

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. What i did is:

- goto `/library/application support/bitcoin/blocks`
- renamed the `index` folder to `index1`
- started bitcoin-qt again

The application started reindexing again but my wallet keys are still there.

Answer (score 1):

You can safely delete any Bitcoin-qt files as long as you let the `wallet.dat` file stay.